# Change media query using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to set media queries manually. I have some `JavaScript` algorithm that tells me what to choose, suppose it is `IsMediaA()`.

```
@media A { display: block; }
@media B { display: inline-block; }
```

Is it possible to change used media query depending on `IsMediaA()` value?

Comment: Why would you want to change a media query with JavaScript?

Comment: why? o.O why use js to fake what media queries already do?

Comment: Just my curiosity. Someone asked me if this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could do the work.

```
if(IsMediaA()) {

   $('<style />', {
        'text': '@media A { display: block; }'
   }).appendTo('body');

}
```

but it's a lot better to workaround with some state classes and style it property in css file:

js:

```
if(IsMediaA()) $('element').addClass('is-mediaA');
```

css:

```
@media A {
    element.is-mediaA { display: block; }
}
```